# Filtering out PHP shell_exec output result

Tags: php, linux, raspberry-pi, shell-exec

I'm trying to create a method to find Raspberry pi on my network with php and I was wondering how can I filter the result of this so that I can only see the ip address of one specific computer?

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('sudo arp-scan --localnet');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

This is an example of the output when executing the php code.

```
Interface: wlan0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.9.5 with 256 hosts (https://github.com/royhills/arp-scan)

192.168.1.62    b8:29:0b:ed:e0:27   Raspberry Pi Foundation
192.168.1.95    14:6b:00:00:ec:59   (Unknown)
192.168.1.72    24:46:11:00:ee:3f   (Unknown)


15 packets received by filter, 0 packets dropped by kernel
Ending arp-scan 1.9.5: 256 hosts scanned in 3.722 seconds (68.78 hosts/sec). 15 responded
```

I'm trying to find a way to filter all text but leaving the IP address of Raspberry Pi Foundation in this case 192.168.1.62

Comment: Change the command sudo arp-scan --localnet to "sudo arp-scan --localnet | awk '/Raspberry Pi Foundation/ { print $1 }'"

Comment: That didn't work.

Comment: Sorry yes it works I had to add awk  and print  permission in visudo thanks.

Comment: How can I separate the results into urls? I tried this but not luck echo '<a href="'.$output.'/web/">RASPBERRY</a>';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the command

```
sudo arp-scan --localnet
```

to:

```
"sudo arp-scan --localnet | awk '/Raspberry Pi Foundation/ { print $1 }'"
```

Answer (score 0):

preg_match_all works best for these type of problems

```
<?php
$text = 'Interface: wlan0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.9.5 with 256 hosts (https://github.com/royhills/arp-scan)

192.168.1.62    b8:29:0b:ed:e0:27   Raspberry Pi Foundation
192.168.1.95    14:6b:00:00:ec:59   (Unknown)
192.168.1.72    24:46:11:00:ee:3f   (Unknown)


15 packets received by filter, 0 packets dropped by kernel
Ending arp-scan 1.9.5: 256 hosts scanned in 3.722 seconds (68.78 hosts/sec). 15 responded
';
$regMatch = '/(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\ \ \ (.*)\ \ \ (.*)/';
preg_match_all( $regMatch, $text, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($out);

print_r($out[2]);  #vendor array
```